# django social auth get wrong access_token from google oauth2

Tags: python, django, google-oauth

I am integrating google oauth2 to my website using django social auth. 
The problem is that with django social auth , I get an access_token like

> ya29.2QCqpS-uKGXMNOP8yZnN6Z-F5LfVnyd7jwa8TaLP43nTEp2NUPB_p7Hi

While with the code sample from google code
the access token is like :

> ya29.2QCVXKc7XSNR3QxqRVAi0Z8Uz6mvolDGpezbZ9_r_oq7CXt01WvE9oUb90HXaynOLE4J8PjA5pzYDB

The first one does not work while the second one works fine

does anyone have any idea on this ?

Comment: trace the http traffic and see (a) are the calls different, and (b) is the token returned by django the same as received over the wire.

Comment: i added traces to social auth.
the code send the same request to the same url with same parameters  as the sample code.  Both call urllib.urlopen.

Comment: trace rthe actual http traffic (not your program code). If you can paste the good and bad http dialogues, your answer will be there.

Answer (score 0):

all right. 
it turns out to be a problem of scope . 
the sample code set a default scope to mail.google.com while social-auth only have a default scope to read user information.

the difference in length of token must be related to the scope